# Sync Activity with broadCast Receiver issue

Tags: android, android-intent, synchronization, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

I wanna sync my Activity with Google cloud Messaging.
When GCM message Receives Its own receiver get the message and create notification and then broadcast my custom message to activity receiver.

In other hand my Activity has own dynamically registered BroadcastReceiver that Receives my cusom messsages.

now this is a situation:

- when app is open, without clicking on notification, my activity
  receiver receives the message and shows.
- but when activity is closed after clicking on notification noting
  receives and app just opens.

I tried may ways like:

1. register a class BroadCast receiver On maifest. but I cannot sync it with my activity. cause I found that outer Receiver can sysnc with activity just with putextra and then my activity should close and then open again to can get extras!
2. try to broadcast my custom message again on creates notification, but it seems wont work cause I need to broad cast on NotificationClick not onCreate notification.
3. finnaly I tried to Register this internal reciver dynamically on another part of but It cannot reachable.

so if you get my problem what is the best way of solving?

this is my in activity receiver:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i("LOG", "unreciver");
            String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
            WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());

            /**
             * Take appropriate action on this message
             * depending upon your app requirement
             * For now i am just displaying it on the screen
             * */

            //Showing received message
            //lblMessage.append(newMessage + "\n");
            Log.i("LOG", "unreciver messsage:"+newMessage);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            loadReciverDialog(newMessage);
            // Releasing wake lock
            WakeLocker.release();
        }
    };
```

this is the part of service that receive message from GCM and Create notification:

```
     @Override
        protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
            String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

            Log.i("LOG", "GCM service Message "+message);

            displayMessage(context, message);
            // notifies user
            generateNotification(context, message);
        }

 private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

        Log.i("LOG", "genetaret notify");
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");


        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      

    }

}
```

and this part display message:

```
  static void displayMessage(Context context, String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        Log.i("LOG", "commonutils msg="+message);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve this problem in this way:

- I kept the in-Activity Broadcast Receiver and made a function for checking if Extras exist my codes under OnReceive functions works.
- after create notification put message to extra for Main Activity to get them

so my app get message in two way:

1. when app is opens message will gave with receiver
2. when app is closed message will gave to app by extra

but I wanna know if there is a better way to work with one Receiver.